# .Net Core 3.1 Merging JWT and OpenIDConnect Authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, jwt, openid-connect

**Short version:** I am having trouble in merging together the correct Authentication config in my .NET Core MVC Website to allow my users to authenticate against Azure Active Directory, but to also allow a Daemon connection (from a Console App) in, too.

**Long version:**
I've got a .NET Core MVC website, which authenticates against Azure Active Directory perfectly fine when using the following in the ConfigureServices method in the Startup.cs:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddSignIn("AzureAd", Configuration, options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

I am also trying to get my .NET Core Console App to call into the APIs (as a Daemon connection) into the above MVC website *(all is configured in the App Registration section in my Microsoft Azure account)*. I can connect the Console App to the MVC website and it will successfully hit an Action Result in a controller but only if I am using the following in the ConfigureServices method in the Startup.cs of the website:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddProtectedWebApi("AzureAd", Configuration, options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAD", options));
```

[image: Here is a diagram of the architecture...]

**BASICALLY, if I only use the OpenIdConnect option, my web users can access the website but my console app is denied.  If I only use the JwtBearer option, then my Console App can connect, but my web users are denied.**

I have Google-Bing'd all day and I'm struggling to get a mash-up of these two configurations to work without knocking the other out.

I have tried to use the .AddJwtBearer() method, but am completely confused by it:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddSignIn("AzureAd", Configuration, options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
   .AddJwtBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAD", options));
```

How do these work together, such that both can be in place and my web app works through a browser, and the Console App (Daemon) works too?  Can I bind both to my appsettings.json file??

Incidentally, the appsettings.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "zzzzzzzzzzzzzz.onmicrosoft.com",
  "TenantId": "yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy",
  "ClientId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
  "SignedOutCallbackPath ": "/signout-callback-oidc",
  "ClientSecret": "myAzureClientSecret"
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2020-06-15:** 
Having working on/off of this for AGES, I've found a suitable resolution that works, hence my awarding the bounty points to @michael-shterenberg. ALSO, I now know that I have a great deal to learn from @gary-archer and his impressive blog site. I just happened to get success from Michael's input.

Here's the mods to the Startup.cs file, within the ASP.NET Core MVC Web App in the diagram above:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddSignIn("AzureAd", Configuration, options =>     
          Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
            .AddJwtBearer(o =>
            {
                o.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
                o.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = false;
                o.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
            });

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("UserAndApp", builder =>
        {                    
             builder.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

builder.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

             builder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        });
    });
```

...coupled with the use of the following attribute on the Controller that I'm trying to call from the Daemon app.

```
[Authorize("UserAndApp")]
```

My users can still log into the website using the Azure Active Directory processes and now my automated processes can log in, too.

In case anyone is struggling to understand how the Azure App Registration side of all of this works, try this really explanatory blog post:

[Secure a .NET Core API using Bearer Authentication](https://dotnetplaybook.com/secure-a-net-core-api-using-bearer-authentication/)

(I wish that I had seen that earlier, when I was trying to get my head around how the Azure App Registration process works!)

Comment: Using multiple authentication schemes might be the direction to take: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-multiple-authentication-schemes

Comment: If I understand correctly: User must be **Authenticated** and ConsoleApp must be **Authorized** ?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution that worked for me (Tested on ASP .NET Core 2.1 and 3.1)

1. Don't set a default authentication scheme since you have 2 types (Cookies and JWT). i.e. your call to `AddAuthentication` should be without parameters:

```
services.AddAuthentication()
   .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
   .AddJwtBearer(o=> {
       o.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
       o.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = false;
       o.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
});
```

- Note that I explicitly didn't bind your AD configuration because **/common** is needed to be applied to the authority (or the tenant id)
- Also I set validation for audience and issuer to false so that any AAD token will work for testing. You should obviously set the correct audience/issuer
- I used `AddAzureAd` and not `AddSignIn` (is that a custom external library you are using?)

  2. Create a policy that accepts both authentication schemes:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("UserAndApp", builer =>
    {
        builer.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        builer.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        builer.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    });
});
```

- Replace this with your existing authorization setup

  3. Use the new policy name in your controller:

```
[Authorize("UserAndApp")]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

**Some explanation on the mechanics:**

You don't want to setup automatic authentication scheme since this will be the default schema run in the authorization middleware, while you have 2 different types

The policy will try run both authentication handlers, if one of them succeeds then authentication succeeded

**Note**: if you send a request with an invalid Bearer token, both authetnication handlers will fail, in this case the `AzureADDefaults` will "win" since it actually implement a challenge method and will redirect you (status code 302), so make sure to handle this in your app

Comment: Btw, my code sample used ```AddJwtBearer```, you can also use ```AddProtectedWebApi``` (which simply uses ```AddJwtBearer``` behind the scene and provides a layer of abstraction to better utilize the AzureAdOptions)

Comment: Thanks for this - I've tried to implement as you've suggested, but get the following:  
 InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'AzureAD'. The registered schemes are: Cookies, OpenIdConnect, Bearer. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().Add[SomeAuthHandler]("AzureAD",...)?

Comment: I actually can't find any documentation on your ```AddSignIn``` method (I used ```AddAzureAD``` for my sample), looks like it register a different scheme names. @BrettRigby, can you try adding all the 3 (without AzureAd) schemes to the policy: ```builer.AuthenticationSchemes.Add("Cookies");``` ```builer.AuthenticationSchemes.Add("OpenIdConnect");``` ```builer.AuthenticationSchemes.Add("Bearer");```

Comment: @BrettRigby did you solve that?

Answer (score -1):

It feels like the architecture is not quite right, and you need to separate the 2 roles performed by your Web Back End:

**CURRENT WEB ONLY ARCHITECTURE**

- You have a Web UI front end that uses auth cookies
- You have a Web Back End that requires cookies for view requests
- You have a Web Back End that requires cookies for API requests
- You have a Console Client that cannot use cookies so cannot call API entry points

**MULTI CLIENT ARCHITECTURE**

You'll need to update the web back end to include API entry points that are secured by OAuth 2.0 access tokens and not by cookies. The console app will then be able to call your web back end.

**.NET CORE SUB PATHS**

Introduce an additional /api subpath in your web back end. The **UseWhen** feature will allow you to do this without impacting other web back end behaviour:

```
/*
 * Apply API behaviour to only subpaths, without impacting the rest of the app
 */ 
app.UseWhen(
ctx => ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/api")),
api => {
  api.useAuthentication();
  api.useJwtBearer();
});
```

**EXAMPLE .NET CORE API**

For an example that uses subpaths, see my [Sample .Net Core API](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore). The [startup class](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.netcore/blob/master/src/host/startup/Startup.cs) is where ASP.Net middleware is wired with different authenticaiton handling for different subpaths.

**FUTURE POSSIBILITIES**

Once you have the above logical separation you could potentially evolve it further in future, eg to a completely cookieless model:

- Develop APIs as completely independent components based only on tokens
- Update the Web UI to an SPA that uses client side security libraries

My blog at https://authguidance.com follows this approach, and my sample APIs all support any type of client.

Comment: Hi Gary - thanks for the suggestion, although I think it's a fairly simple architecture in itself... I could swap out the MVC site for a SPA site, but don't know how much that would help. I've added an image to explain the architecture a little further, as I think my explanation makes it sound more complicated than it is.

Comment: Ok Brett - thanks for explaining - I updated my original answer - I think the UseWhen feature is what you need

Comment: Thanks for this - have been reading your blog post as a result and can see that my mind has been blown about the stuff I don't yet understand on security in .NET.